# Rails - Create an object with user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, build, associations

Hello everybody I'm trying to make an app with a user and children with has_many and belongs_to association.

When I try to modify children controller I have this error : undefined method `build'. 
This is my controller :

```
# GET /enfants/new
  def new
    @enfant = current_user.enfants.build
  end

  # GET /enfants/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /enfants
  # POST /enfants.json
  def create
    @enfant = current_user.build(enfant_params)

    respond_to do |format|
  if @enfant.save
    format.html { redirect_to @enfant, notice: 'Enfant was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @enfant }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @enfant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

I tried some of answers in this website but there is no solution to my problem.
Can you help me please ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

change 
`current_user.build(enfant_params)` in `create` action to 
`current_user.enfants.new(enfant_params)`